# CouchDB filtering UTC dates by month and year

Tags: javascript, date, couchdb

I save a UTC timestamp for every document in one of my Couch databases.
I want to query and filter those documents based on a specific month of a year. For this purpose I created a view with the following map function:

```
function(doc) {
    var date = new Date(doc.activity.date);
    emit([doc.user, date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCFullYear()], doc.activity.distance);
}
```

I query this view with for example: *?key=["1edd367d08770ea34586dbe6dc03ea2c",3,2013]*, which works perfectly fine as long as the UTC and local time is in the same month.

What I am asking is how can I ensure that a query like this returns all documents of a month, where the month is defined by the clients local time and not UTC?

The client is a JavaScript based Web-Client, but the query is handled through a NodeJS API in the back end.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the client would send?

Comment: No, I am sorry but I just started with the CouchDB view for this feature and depending on my options the client will send what ever is needed an possible. For example the month and the year as integers and the user id (which is not important here) and maybe the timezones offset if needed.

Comment: As my answer states, there is the ISO 8601 standard which may be useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am asking is how can I ensure that a query like this returns all documents of a month, where the month is defined by the clients local time and not UTC?

Find the start of the client's month and the start of the client's next month.  These will form the range to query.  For example:

```
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1);
var end = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1);
```

Then you will need to decide the best way to get this as UTC to pass to the database.  For example:

```
var startUTC = start.toISOString();
var endUTC = end.toISOString();
```

(I am not sure of the specifics for CouchDB, so adjust if necessary.)

Then you need to do a *range query* in your database.  You can't just match on year and month because your data is in UTC and the edges will not necessarily line up with your client's time zone.

I'm not familiar with Couch's syntax, but in SQL it would be something like this:

```SQL
... WHERE activityDate >= startUTC AND activityDate < endUTC
```

Since we passed the start of the *next* month as the end date, make sure that perform an exclusive `<` and not an inclusive `<=` operation.  Only the start date should be inclusive.

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I came up with myself a minute ago and wanted to post. For those interested the _rage query_ for CouchDB looks something like this: _?startkey=["1edd367d08770ea34586dbe6dc03ea2c",1370037600000]&endkey=["1edd367d08770ea34586dbe6dc03ea2c",1372629599999]_ where *1370037600000* and *1372629599999* define the range.

Comment: I was looking for the range query for couch, but couldn't find how to do an *exclusive* end date.  If it is fully inclusive, then make sure you subtract one before passing it through.

Comment: There is a parameter for _exclusive_ end keys, called inclusive_end. For more information: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

Answer (score 0):

> What I am asking is how can I ensure that a query like this returns
>   all documents of a month, where the month is defined by the clients
>   local time and not UTC?

If the client sends his local time, he must do so with a reference as to which timezone he is located in.
Otherwise, he must use UTC or GMT.

Without including the timezone, you would basically have to detect what timezone the client is located in and make assumptions which would not work out (e.g. a laptop located on a italian IP may be set with american time).

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

The ISO 8601 format has time zone designator that would allow clients to send their localtime but with the attached time offset.

**Couchdb supports this ISO 8601 format:**

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/14485
- http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/IsoFormattedDateAsDocId .

Remaining would be for you to do your conversions/comparisons etc to UTC/Unix time/ etc... whatever format works for you in order to be able to compare the KEY with the DATA.

**The main point is that your comparing datetimes that are converted to the same timeoffset or UTC (no time offset).**